# Continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ at a point

Tags: functions, continuity

I have some problem to understand the definition of a continuous function in a point.

I have $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$  and I want to check the continuity of the function above in the point $x_0 = 0$ or for all the $x_0 \ge 0$.

Using the relation between $|f(x) -f(x_0)|< \epsilon$ and $|x - x_0| < \delta$ that states: $\forall\epsilon \in \Bbb R, \exists\delta\in\Bbb R : \forall x \in domain \mathcal (f): |x-x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$, how can I check continuity at a point?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$|f(x) - f(c)| = |\sqrt{x}  - \sqrt{c}|  \leq\sqrt{|x-c|}$ this shows the continuity of $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: how should I see the continuity from that?

Comment: if |f(x)-f(c)|< epsilon then your delta will be epsilon^2